How to Handle Point-in-Time Restore with Azure PostgreSQL and Terraform?
I'm using an Azure PostgreSQL database and need to perform a point-in-time restore (PITR) as part of a disaster recovery drill. I can successfully restore the database to a new server and update my application to point to this new server.
However, I'm deploying the database server using Infrastructure as Code (Terraform). After performing a PITR, I end up with a new server that is not represented in my Terraform code.
My questions are:

Is there a way to properly replace the existing server with the point-in-time data state while keeping my Terraform code in sync?

Should I delete the previous server after restoring, or is there a better approach to managing this situation with Terraform?
Any insights or best practices would be greatly appreciated!



please share the code you tried @kamalrathnayake

To keep your Terraform state in sync after a PITR, you can import the newly restored server into your Terraform state using the terraform import command. This way, you avoid inconsistencies between your infrastructure and Terraform code. After importing, you can safely delete the old server if it’s no longer needed.  @kamalRathnayake

postgresql_flexible_server resource has enough options to allow you to have a point-in-time restore of postgres server.
You need to play with following options:
create_mode - set it to PointInTimeRestore
point_in_time_restore_time_in_utc - put time here
source_server_id - put source db id here
source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server

This does not address the state management issues, but this would be the approach for performing the initial restore using Terraform. It's important to note that you can't change create mode directly on the original server resource because it would trigger a recreate which isn't typically desired behavior when dealing with backups,

Azure currently does not support in-place restores using the Point-in-Time Recovery feature of Azure PSQL Flexible server, so you have to always initially create a standalone flexible server resource. There is no one-click way to get Terraform to recognize this newly restored server without adding it to your Terraform code first and then using Terraform import commands. Deleting the original server will not address any state management issues.
The other alternative outside of imports would be to add some additional complexity to your Terraform code to conditionally create the restored server and manage in-line import blocks. Given that approach requires a bit of a deep dive I wrote an article here for further review.
